# how to make format files manually?

Tags: format-files

In my MikTeX installation in Windows 10, it only has three mft files, cmbase.mft, mplain.mft and plain.mft. When I use mo.exe to build other format files, it fails. How can I build other mft files manually?

Comment: You will need to find out why the build of other formats fails. Are there any error messages?

Comment: It says "Unknown engine: etex"

Comment: Sorry you are not giving enough information and I have currently too much to do and can't spent time trying to extract more from you.

Comment: starting with command line: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=etex --dest-name=etex etex.src --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose
Unknown engine: etex